# How to get the returned value from a method that is called if a button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

So I have a button which when pressed, calls the following method through the use of the actionListener:

```
public Die[] roll(){

    Die[] playerRoll = new Die[5];

    //code goes in here...

    return playerRoll;
}
```

I would like to access the returned playerRoll array after the button is pressed but I am not sure how to do that. This is what I tried:

```
Die[] returnedArray  = throwButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

but it gives me an error saying `Type mismatch: Cannot convert from void to Die[]`

My whole code works including the code in the actionListener, I just simply want to access the returned variable. If you need additional code then I'll edit this post.

EDIT. I tried pasting the code as less as possible as there are a lot of code so I tried pasting the relevant things:

```
 public class Dice {
 static JButton throwButton = new JButton("Throw!");
static JButton scoreTitle = new JButton("Score!");
 static JLabel playerRoll1 = new JLabel();
static JLabel playerRoll2 = new JLabel();
static JLabel playerRoll3 = new JLabel();

 Die[] playerCurrentRoll;
 boolean playerRolled = false;
 static JButton throwButton = new JButton("Throw!");
 frame.getContentPane().add(scoreTitle);
 frame.getContentPane().add(playerRoll1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(playerRoll2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(playerRoll3);
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    frame.setContentPane(jp);

    frame.getContentPane().add(throwButton);
 throwButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
 frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
}

public Die[] roll() {
Die[] playerRoll = new Die[5];
//A lot of code in here but it basically populates the playRoll array. 
//This part of the code does work.
return playerRoll

}

public void scoreMethod() {
for (int i =0; i < playerCurrentRoll.length; i++) {
        humanTotal += playerCurrentRoll[i].getValue();
        humanScore.setText(Integer.toString(humanTotal));
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
Dice diceobj = new Dice();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == Dice.throwButton) {
        // diceobj.roll();
        diceobj.playerCurrentRoll = diceobj.roll();
        System.out.println(diceobj.playerCurrentRoll);

        diceobj.computerCurrentRoll = diceobj.roll();
    }else if(e.getSource() == Dice.scoreTitle){
        diceobj.scoreMethod();
        System.out.println("Called the score method");

    }


}
```

}

It may seem that I haven't pasted my code. Some parts might be missing but I can assure you everything works. I know this because when I press the Throw button, it gives me the output of the array (as seen in the myactionlistener class in the system.out.println). gives me the memory address of the array. It just doesn't work when I press the score button and it points me to the line that contains the error which is:

```
for (int i =0; i < playerCurrentRoll.length; i++) {
```

located in the scoreMethod(); in the Dice class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Die[] returnedArray; // member variable

// Inside the container's constructor
throwButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());

public Die[] roll(){
    Die[] playerRoll = new Die[5];

    //code goes in here...
    return playerRoll;
}

// Your custom ActionListener
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void onActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         returnedArray = roll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really even need the `class MyActionListener`? What is wrong with anonymous classes?

Comment: The OP used a custom `ActionListener` class. I wanted to keep it that way.

Comment: @Sparta That's a good way of doing it. But i'm currently getting a nullpointerException. I think its something to do with my assigning..

Comment: @TarikhChouhan if you show me more code, we could figure this out.

Comment: @Sparta Oh my dayssss I can't believe I made that mistake!! I fixed the error now. What happened was in the scoreMethod, I retinitlised the playerRoll array. Thanks for the help though. Much appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome :) It's a good thing that you figured it on your own !

Answer (score 2):

You would just do:

```
returnedArray = roll();
```

inside of the action listener and make Die[] returnedArray a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You basicly have to add and `ActionListener` to your button:

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        }
 });
```

The `actionPerformed` method is called every time you click on the button.

So inside its body you just have to call:

```
Die[] returnedArray = roll();
```

After you press the button `returnedArray` will be equal to the array returned by the `roll()` method.

Hope that's clear enough.